# LabelEncoder implementation in r

Tags: r

G$name - character column of dataframe

```
labels_name <- unique(G$name)

LabelEncoder <- function(value, labels) {
   r <- as.numeric(which(labels == value))
   returnValue(r)
}

G$name1 <- LabelEncoder(G$name, labels_name)
```

Execution of code above generate next error:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "name1", value = c(1, 4, 7, 10, 11,  : 
  replacement has 100650 rows, data has 302194
In addition: Warning message:
In labels == value :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by the next way:

Because G$name is a vector I used next additional function

```
LabelEncoder1 <- function(x, labels) {
    r <- sapply(x, LabelEncoder, labels)
}

G$name1 <- LabelEncoder1(G$name, labels_name)
```